# Change data in Pandas dataframe by column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have some data I imported from a excel spreadsheet as a csv. I created a dataframe using Pandas, and want to change a specific column. The column contains strings such as "5.15.1.0.0". I want to change these strings to floats like "5.15100".

So far I've tried using the method "replace" to change every instance in that column:

```
df['Fix versions'].replace("5.15.1.0.0", 5.15.1.0.0)
```

this however does not work. When I reprint the dataframe after the replace methods are called it shows me the same dataframe where no changes are made. Is it not possible to change a string to a float using replace? If not does anyone know another way to do this?

I could parse each string and remove the "." but I'd prefer not to do it this way as some of the strings represent numbers of different lengths and decimal place values.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the parameter "inplace" which default is false. Changing this to true will change the dataframe in place, which can be type casted.

```
df['Fix versions'].replace(to_replace="5.15.1.0.0", value="5.15100", inplace=True)
```